# Angularjs Promises

Tags: angularjs, node.js

Hello guys i use `angularjs 1.3.0` john papa style,  i have two promises... how i can execute second promise if the first promise return me true, anyone can help ? this is my code :

```
function signup() {
            var promises = [updateProfile(vm.user), checkCaptcha( vm.captchaData)];
            return dataservice.ready(promises).then(function () {
               // there call promise in dataservice
            })

        }
```

i need to call updateProfile if checkCaptcha == true ..

I'v made like this :

```
function signup() {
            $q.when(dataservice.checkCaptcha(vm.captchaData))
            .then(test)

            function test(result){
                console.log(result);
                if(result){
              var promises = [updateProfile(vm.user)];
            return dataservice.ready(promises).then(function () {
                // there call only updateProfile (put request)
            })
                }
            }


        }
```

Is bad or i'm in the right way ? 
best regards.

Comment: The `angular` tag is only for Angular 2,4,5,... which is an entirely different framework than AngularJS.

Comment: what's the error you are getting?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Sorry man

Comment: @RahulSharma Hello, i get nothing that work fine but i don't know if i'm in the right way.. for example 2

Comment: @Nemecek no problem. Just wanted to let you know for the future :)

Answer (score 0):

Lets say we have this two functions:

```
function doFirst() {return $q.when({isAuth:true})};
function checkAuth(user) { 
         if (!user.isAuth) { 
               return $http.get('auth/user/111'); 
          } 
         return user; 
      }
```

Then we can do this chain. 
doFirst().then(checkAuth).then(workWithUser);

Two important points.

- Your check function should always return value. (In another case you
  will get undefined). Feel free to return promise or plain value.
- You should keep in mind that workWithUser
  function should always take one-type object - Authenticated User. This makes your code more predictable.

Btw, I have npm package for such function composition
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@drag13/when-do
May be it will be usefull.

Comment: Thnaks for your awesome reply, but your example is the same if i do $q.when(checkAut).then(updateProfile)   right?

Comment: @Nemecek 
Sure you can go this way. You can even do this in one function checkAuth. 
But the main idea is to extract logic into separate function that can be easily tested and then combine them into the chain.